# Dynamically setting data of dropdown cell in handsontable

Tags: jquery, handsontable

Hi this is my beginning with Handsontable and I am trying to implement a functionality wherein the dropdown values of a cell depends on the value of another cell.
On change event of cell 1, I want to load the new data source to row 2 which is a dropdown cell.

When a user selects a value in hotel cell the ajax call is made to find the room types. I want the room types to be available in the room type cell adjacent to changed hotel field.

Help me on this please.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [afterChange](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.25.0/Hooks.html#event:afterChange) in order to trigger changes in cell 1.
Then you can use [setCellMeta](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.25.0/Core.html#setCellMeta) to update the data source of cell number 2.
Finally, take a look at the [autocomplete with ajax source](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.25.0/demo-autocomplete.html#strict-ajax), since dropdown is based on autocomplete, it will work the same way.

Your code will look like that:

```
var myTable = new Handsontable($(...), {
    ...,
    afterChange: function (change, source) {
        //choose the source you want to trigger, accordingly to the doc
        if((source == 'edit' || source == 'autofill' || source == 'paste'))
        {
            /*if you have multiples lines in your handsontable, then 
              the change array has one line per line in your table */
            for(var i = 0 ; i < change.length ; i++) {
                // I suppose here cell 2 is in row 2 (second argument)
                myTable.setCellMeta(
                     change[i][0],
                     2,
                     'source',
                     function(query,process) {
                         $.ajax({...})
                     }
                 )
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you but now my code is not making an ajax request, here is the code ` afterChange: function (change, source) {

                if((source == 'edit' || source == 'autofill' || source == 'paste' || source=="edit"&&change[0][1]==6 && change.length==1))
                {hot.setCellMeta(
                    change[0][1],7, 'source',
                     function() {$.ajax({
                        url: 'get_room_types', dataType: 'json', method:'GET', data: {hotel_name: change[0][3]}, success: function (response) { process(response.data);
                         }}); } )}`

Comment: Try changing the parenthesing in the condition `if((source == 'edit' || source == 'autofill' || source == 'paste') && change[0][1]==6 && change.length==1)`, and in setCellMeta, you use change[0][1] as line number but it's the column number. I guess you changed the url, because I think this one won't work

Comment: i have made the changes but still the ajax request is not called up.

Comment: Can you please add a bigger part of your code in your question?

Comment: here is the fiddle for the same [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/vnoh9gtp/)

Comment: The call is made when you click in the dropdown. Add the error function to your ajax call so you can see what happen

Comment: Thank you for helping me @nicolas-barlogis Now my ajax call is running and i am getting the desired data but that data is not shown up in the adjacent dropdown.

Comment: If you don't have solved your problem you can put the source code of your page in the jsfiddle (the code you put in the fiddle contains php), I will take a look.

Comment: any news on your problem?

Comment: @nicoals-barlogis Sorry for late reply and thanks a lot for  helping. Yes the problem is solved with your solution :)